# Gnu make: ifeq and $*

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to test the value of `$*` in a recipe.

```
main.txt: main.dat
    # ...
other.txt: other.dat
    # ...

%.dat: 
    # ...
ifeq "$*" "other"
    # .., do something special for 'other'
endif
```

However, I cannot seem to get the syntax right. No matter how I write the `ifeq "$*" "other"` the statemen is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic variables like `$*` are expanded after make parsed the makefiles, so you cannot use them in conditionals. But you can use the shell conditionals, instead:

```
%.dat:
    if [ "$*" = "other" ]; then \
        do something special for other; \
    else \
        do something else for others than other; \
    fi
```

But as pattern rules have lower precedence than non pattern rules you could as well try:

```
other.dat:
    do something for other

%.dat:
    do something else for others than other
```

Comment: Put a bit differently, automatic variables only have a value _inside a recipe_ (indented with a TAB).  They are not set outside a recipe.  On the other hand, recipes are shell scripts, not make syntax, so you cannot use make syntax like `ifeq` inside a recipe (you cannot indent it with a TAB) because it will be passed to the shell, not parsed by make, and the shell doesn't know anything about `ifeq`.  So, you can't use automatic variables with make constructs like `ifeq`: they exist in completely separate domains that don't overlap.